# Which would be right service to use in PHP client library for Google to get basic info like name and email address?

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am following [this](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php) tutorial from last year, which teaches how to use Login with google for your website and get basic user info. In tutorial they are using Google_Oauth2Service class, which I could not find in [PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) I downloaded.

There is a similar service named oAuth2 but it seems to require Google+ account. I do not want to use Google+ service.

Comment: There are often several different ways to do similar things with the Google APIs and they don't necessarily work together, so you are probably better off using one of the example files included in that Github repository for the library you are using rather than from the tutorial you found. Google has also been transitioning their login with Google functionality to login with Google+ but it serves essentially the same function, just in a slightly different way.

Comment: I have no problem in using Google +, but it not available for users of Google apps free edition.

Comment: Had you already considered services like [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/contact-importers/gmail)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to use is the Plus API, with the people.get function: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get. The function will work for all users as long as you request the `profile` scope - they don't have to have Google+ profiles or have granted the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope.